# How to get "timing advance" parameter for 5G Telephony API in ANDROID

Tags: android

I am trying to get the "timing advance" parameter for 5G Telephony API in ANDROID. The parameter is available in LTE API but I found no such parameter in the 5G API.

In LTE API I use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellSignalStrengthLte#getTimingAdvance() to get the "timing advance" parameter.

Can anybody suggest any 5G API to fetch the parameter.

Comment: This is not getting enough attention, it seems. I ran into a same problem...